# doesn't draw depth texture in framebuffer

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shadow

In attempt to draw model in depth texture of Chrome gives out a mistake:
WebGL: 
**INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: drawArrays: internalformat of the attached texture isn't color-renderable**

the texture and framebuffer are created so:

```
var fb=self.gl.createFramebuffer();
self.gl.bindFramebuffer(self.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

var rb=self.gl.createRenderbuffer();
self.gl.bindRenderbuffer(self.gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
self.gl.renderbufferStorage(self.gl.RENDERBUFFER, self.gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16,256,256);
self.gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(self.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, self.gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,self.gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);

var texture_rtt=self.gl.createTexture();
self.gl.bindTexture(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture_rtt);
self.gl.texParameteri(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, self.gl.LINEAR);
self.gl.texParameteri(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, self.gl.LINEAR);
self.gl.texParameteri(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, self.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
self.gl.texParameteri(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, self.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, self.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
self.gl.texImage2D(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, self.gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, 256, 256,0, self.gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, self.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);

self.gl.framebufferTexture2D(self.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, self.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture_rtt, 0);

self.gl.bindTexture(self.gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
self.gl.bindFramebuffer(self.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

The example can be found :[here](https://webgl-project-toly19.c9.io/index.html)

Comment: as starmole points out, you're creating `DEPTH_COMPONENT` texture on the 4th from the bottom line and then trying to attach that as `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. Change the `gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT` to `gl.RGBA` and `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT` to `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can not attach a depth texture as color:

```
 framebufferTexture2D(self.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, self.gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
```

Is wrong. You can only attach a depth texture to depth. DEPTH_ATTACHMENT. If you want to render depth as color you have to do that in the shader.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786

```
var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

var rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 256, 256);
gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);

var rttTexture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rttTexture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 256, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, rttTexture, 0);
```